# How to properly iterate over an array elements with Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to render a table adding row per each objects in an array.

I got a **Controller** like:

```
app.controller('SignUpController',function ($scope, $http) {

    var that = this 


    that.users = []


    that.queryUsers = function() {
        console.log("I'm being triggered")

        $http.get("/existingUsers").

        success(function (data,status,headers,config) {
            console.log(data)
            that.users = data
            console.log(that.users)
        }).

        error(function (data,status, headers, config) {
            console.log(status)
        })
    }

})
```

And the table markup:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <th ng-repeat="th in ['mail','Administrador','Miembro desde']">{{th}}</th>

        <tr ng-repeat="p in signup.users">
            <td>{{p._id}}</td>
            <td>{{p.mail}}</td>
            <td>{{p.admin}}</td>
        </tr>

</table>
```

Ttable is within a div with `ng-controller="SignUpController as signup"`. When I click a button I trigger `queryUsers` actually seein results in browser console:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

Both `mail` and `_id` are existing attributes per each object.

So the AJAX is being done and the array I should be iterating and rendering to HTML rows actually exists and is populated, but no rows are shown.

Why?

## Edit

I tried not modifying the scope:

```
app.controller('SignUpController', function ($scope,$http) {

    $scope.users = []

    $scope.queryUsers = function() {
        
        console.log("I'm being triggered")

        $http.get("/existingUsers").

        success(function (data,status,headers,config) {
            console.log(data)
            $scope.users = data
            console.log($scope.users)
        }).

        error(function (data,status, headers, config) {
            console.log(status)
        })
    }

})


<div class="tab-pane" id="usecase11" ng-controller="SignUpController">
    
        <h3>Colaboradores</h3>

        <div class="row">
            
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <th ng-repeat="th in ['mail','Administrador','Miembro desde']">{{th}}</th>

                        <tr ng-repeat="p in users">
                            <td>{{p._id}}</td>
                            <td>{{p.mail}}</td>
                            <td>{{p.admin}}</td>
                            <td style="border:none;"><a class="close" ng-click="">$</a></td>
                            <td style="border:none;"><a class="close" ng-click="">*</a></td>
                        </tr>

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**However, again I can see such array printed at browser console but nothing rendered to HTML**

Here is the *evidence* that queryUsers is being called and that `$scope.users` is getting *something* after it.

[image]

Something interesting is that I got: `{{users}}` right after the table and it's displaying an empty array.

[image]

Just in case this is the GET handling server code:

```
app.get('/existingUsers',function (request, response) {

    
    membersCollection.find({},{"password":0}, function (err, data) {

        if (err) response.send(404)
        
        else {
            
            data.toArray(function (err, docs) {
                if (err) {
                    
                    console.log(error)
                    response.send("Error")
                }

                response.send(JSON.stringify(docs, null, 4))
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: It should be: `$scope.users = [];` and `$scope.queryUsers = function(){...};`

Comment: and `ng-repeat="p in users"`

Comment: Did the whole changes you propose, not working

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle or something?

Answer (score 2):

You don't modify the `$scope`. Here is the corrected code:

```
app.controller('SignUpController',function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.users = []

    $scope.queryUsers = function() {
        console.log("I'm being triggered")

        $http.get("/existingUsers").

        success(function (data,status,headers,config) {
            console.log(data)
            $scope.users = data
            console.log($scope.users)
        }).

        error(function (data,status, headers, config) {
            console.log(status)
        })
    }

})
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <th ng-repeat="th in ['mail','Administrador','Miembro desde']">{{th}}</th>

    <tr ng-repeat="p in users">
        <td>{{p._id}}</td>
        <td>{{p.mail}}</td>
        <td>{{p.admin}}</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: I did exactly the same as you suggest but it's not working. I'm editing my question now ..